# Changing default file name to its current value from Database

Tags: php, html, file

Here has been thinking what would be the solution of this problem.

The default value of a input type = "file" is - File no chosen.

Assuming that I have already uploaded an image. Which is cart/uploads/image.jpg,

so I have to echo the image directory and its image name to the attribute "value"
but seems doesnt work.
My second solution is to use 90px width to hide File no chosen. But that doesnt make sense because it echos the no value since theres no echo that calls the existing file.
My third solution is to put "Required" to its tag, so whenever the user will update an item. He/she has to put again the image inorder to update it. But it should not be that way. I want to display the existing image from the value in database so when the user doesnt change the image. It stays the same.
'having trouble to explain this, not so fluent in english' sorry in advance.

```
 <div class="custom-file">
 <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Product Image</label>
 <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id=image" name="image" 
 style="width: 90px"  value="cart1.10/'.$row['product_image'].'" 
 title="cart1.10/'.$row['product_image'].'" required>
 <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile" ><img 
 src="cart1.10/'.$row['product_image'].'" width=100 height=100></label>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That won't work. The user has to manually select a file to upload.

How about this: if no image exists yet, make the file input `required`, otherwise don't make it `required`. In neither case should you try to populate a default `value`. Then, on the server side, just ensure that a file has been provided if no image exists yet and only conditionally save the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
#div-file {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -moz-appearance:    button;
    appearance:         button;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;  
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Sans-serif;
}

</style>
 <div class="custom-file">
 <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Product Image</label>
 // if no uploaded image just the regular input file
 <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="image" name="image">
 // else this
<label for="uploadFile">
    <div id="div-file">Image name</div>
</label>
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" style="display:none" />
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile" ><img src="cart1.10/'.$row['product_image'].'" width=100 height=100></label>
 // endif
 </div>
```

You can't add value on a file for security purposes but you might want to do some tricks to display it as you want. just change something on it, to fits your code.

Answer (score 0):

in this snippet you can see an option.
You can hide the file input, and show a label, 
in this way the message "File no chosen" will not be displayed, but clicking on the label will open the box for choosing image

```js
$('#picture').on('change', function(e) {
 if(e.target.files.length){
   getBase64(e.target.files[0])
     .then(data => $("#img").attr('src', data));
      //your code to upload image
  }
});

function getBase64(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });
}
```

```css
#picture {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <label for="picture" class="btn btn-primary">
    Upload picture
    </label>
    <input type="file" id="picture">
    <img id="img" width="200px" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200">
    <!-- in this place, you can put your php echo -->
</form>
```